# No operations allowed after connection closed when using Singleton pattern

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, singleton

In the following code I have a library database to which I add book and its details. In DbUtils I have to use singleton pattern to return connection, but when I do so I get a SQL error saying:

```
SQL State: S1009
No operations allowed after statement closed.SQL State: 08003
No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

Without using singleton pattern everything works just fine, but like this it just keeps throwing errors. I tried to move `preparedStatement()` to the `DbUtils` class, or to use singleton pattern with it too but nothing works. Why does my code closes the connection too soon?

```
public class BookRepository {
        public static void insertBook(String bookName, String genre, String language) {
        try (Connection con =connect.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_BOOK)) {

            preparedStatement.setString(1, bookName);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, genre);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, language);
            int row = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class DbUtils {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    static {
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
        final String  USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "12345";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Connected to database");
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the Singleton pattern, just with the fact that your connection has been closed. Also: there is a difference between a static field and the Singleton pattern. I don't see the pattern anywhere in your code.

Comment: You are using a try-with-resources statement that will close the resource (=your connection) after using it in your `insertBook` method. And you only use one connection that you create once and then return for every `getConnection` call. So In Short what happens is: 1. You create `Connection conn` 2. Use that connection in `insertBook` method 3. close that connection after using. 4. `Connection conn` is now closed and can no longer be used.